# Context-aware dataset of movies or music

Tags: data-request, licensing, language, programming, music

Looking for access to context aware dataset(s) of movies or music.
Context aware dataset should contain user related information, such as user gender, mood, time, social, location, weather, emotions as well as item related information like genre of movie/music, year, director etc.

Comment: Coul you please give an example of a particular movie and its associated context? That will allow us to answer your question better, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

EchoNest (http://the.echonest.com/) provides at least 'genre' information about music. EchoNest is not 100% 'open', but per their 'ground rules': 'terms of service allow for most reasonable non-commercial uses' (developer.echonest.com/docs/v4#ground-rules).

You can get a rate-limited API key for free, requiring only attribution. So depending on the project, it might be a good fit, or at least a starting point.

Comment: echonest looks closed/proprietary - i just did a quick sweep, and i don't see anything in regards to it being open...i could be wrong, but if i'm not, this reponse is not appropriate for open data.

Comment: Per the 'ground rules': 'terms of service allow for most reasonable non-commercial uses' (http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4#ground-rules). You can get a rate-limited API key for free, requiring only attribution. So depending on the project, it seemed like it could be a fit to me. But if I am missing something in the definition of 'open' being used here, and you could point me in the right direction, please let me know.

Comment: @i_am_Halloran I think it's open enough to be a useful answer, but if you have a minute, it might help to edit your answer to integrate the follow-up. It's nice to have them be self-contained.